# Building and archetype to Maven, Velocity ParseErrorException with JSP's

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

I'm trying to build a multimodule archetype with Maven to a project. When I include my JSP's I get an exception from Velocity.

```
[INFO] Parent element not overwritten in /home/gortiz/workspaces/archetype/miPrueba/miPrueba-new-aw/pom.xml
[ERROR] Parser Exception: archetype-resources/__rootArtifactId__-new-aw/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/open/login.jsp
[ERROR] org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.ParseException: Encountered " eq 1}\">\n
```

I found this URL but, it doesn't work to me.
http://yajdb.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/maven-archetype-creation-conflicts-between-jsp-and-velocity-templates/

My configuration file is:

```
<modules>
        <module id="${implantation}-new-aw" dir="__rootArtifactId__-new-aw"
            name="${implantation}-new-aw">
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>                 
                </fileSet>
                <!-- <fileSet filtered=”true” packaged=”false”>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/**/*.jsp</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </fileSet>-->                
                <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>                                                          
                <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/**/*.*</include>
                    </includes>                 
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </module>       
    </modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove or make the filtered attribute false in your jsp configuration and also in for resources.

**filtered=true**, Filesets can be filtered, which means the selected files will be used as Velocity templates. 

**filtere=false**, They can be non-filtered, which means the selected files will be copied without modification.

Default value is: false.

```
<fileSet packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```